# Performance difference between Linq Select and ToList

Tags: c#, linq

Would the following linq expressions both result in the same performance?

In my conjured up scenario, my table, MyData. has 25 columns, and 50,000 rows. I am trying to get all MyData records based on a WHERE.

```
var myData = _myDb.Entities<MyData>()
        .ToList()
        .Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Id })
        .Where(y => y.DepartmentId = 1)
        .OrderBy(x => x.Name);
```

vs

```
var myData = _myDb.Entities<MyData>()
        .Where(y => y.DepartmentId = 1)
        .Select(p => new { p.Name, p.Id })
        .OrderBy(x => x.Name)
        .ToList();
```

I think the first query would basically execute a `SELECT * FROM MyData` due to the order of the ToList() in the statement. Costly. All data brought back to client, to then apply ordering and filtering.

Where as the 2nd option would be better, executing a `SELECT Name, Id FROM MyData WHERE DepartmentId = 1 ORDER BY Name` - so smaller set of data, ordered by SQL, in this case.

Or would Linq work this out, and do the latter, regardless?

Comment: It depends on what your data is. If your select is simply transforming to a tuple of string and int (I'm assuming a typo in your code), then your query will select only those fields from the database, which is generally a lot better for performance than selecting the entire table. However, if you need to do specific things in constructing your transformed object, or there is a lot of computation going on that you would prefer to happen in memory as opposed to in the database, then you should materialize first. Going off the example in your question, your second one is probably better.

Comment: You can view the generated sql, and you can profile different scenarios. However common sense does prevail... (until it doesn't), which is why we profile

Comment: `Or would Linq work this out, and do the latter, regardless?` Linq is going to execute your query when it needs to materialize data, which in your case is as soon as you call `ToList`. It's not going to optimize this away on its own

Answer (score 7):

No, LINQ would not work this out regardless.

I have created a sample of your queries using my database in Linq Pad.

The first one is this

```
TelematicDevices
.ToList()
.Where(s => s.sReference.Contains("abc"))
.Select(p => new { p.sReference, p.iDeviceId})
.OrderBy(x => x.sReference)
.Dump();
```

Which generates the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[iDeviceId] AS [iDeviceId], 
    [Extent1].[iDeviceTypeId] AS [iDeviceTypeId], 
    [Extent1].[iGSMProviderId] AS [iGSMProviderId], 
    [Extent1].[sAssetClass] AS [sAssetClass], 
    [Extent1].[iCompanyId] AS [iCompanyId], 
    [Extent1].[iAssetId] AS [iAssetId], 
    [Extent1].[sReference] AS [sReference], 
    [Extent1].[sDescription] AS [sDescription], 
    [Extent1].[sSoftwareId] AS [sSoftwareId], 
    [Extent1].[sIMEI] AS [sIMEI], 

   // ... ALL OTHER COLUMNS IN MY TABLE

    FROM [dbo].[TelematicDevices] AS [Extent1]
GO
```

And the second query

```
TelematicDevices
.Where(s => s.sReference.Contains("abc"))
.Select(p => new { p.sReference, p.iDeviceId })
.OrderBy(x => x.sReference)
.ToList()
.Dump();
```

generates the following SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[iDeviceId] AS [iDeviceId], 
    [Extent1].[sReference] AS [sReference]
    FROM [dbo].[TelematicDevices] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[sReference] LIKE N'%abc%'
    ORDER BY [Extent1].[sReference] ASC
```

As you can see there is a difference.

1st query will select all data and columns - then filter and order by in the application back-end.

2nd query will select only the 2 columns, filter and then order by on the database server.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Dawood! I'm unable to profile my work DB right now. Was going to try this at home, but you have been a gent, and done it for me. Thanks. Answered what I thought. Now I can complete my code review with more confidence. :)